# Invalid floating point operation in kernelbase.dll in windows 10 when moving Delphi 2007 form rapidly

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

I wrote a utility program in Delphi 2007 years ago.  They have worked for years.  In the past six months, some Windows 10 bug fix seems to have caused KernelBase.DLL to crash when I move a form rapidly across the screen.  It seems to occur in a call to sqrt().  The ultimate cause might be in TWinControl.DefaultHandler.  You can see the stack trace at

[image: http://www.jonbondy.com/kernelbase.png]

Has anyone else seen this?  Is there a known work-around?

Comment: Try to disable all FPU exceptions to see if it makes a difference. more info [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40968784/800214)

Comment: That worked!  Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [W10 + Delphi Seattle, TFileOpenDialog + fdoForcePreviewPaneOn = crash on some images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40965443/w10-delphi-seattle-tfileopendialog-fdoforcepreviewpaneon-crash-on-some-im)